# Citrix - Key not valid for use in specified state error in 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, citrix, citrix-receiver

I am trying to install [Citrix Receiver 4.1](http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/windows/receiver-for-windows-41.html) on my machine running Windows 8.1.

I am getting following error :
"Key not valid for use in specified state."

I am getting the same error when I try to install Citrix XenApp Web Plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: date and time issues with the machine? I've seen another citrix product be picky about that.

Comment: Don't think so, never had any such problems with other applications on my systems.

Comment: My AWESOME IT Support team was able to find work around for the above glitch. He signed out of my Windows account and singed in with his admin ID and installed XenApp plugin. It was successfully installed. After that, we signed in with my credentials and were able to successfully access the Citrix client. (Since this is not the direct solution to the problem, waiting to see if someone can post a direct answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten the same error when attempting to run the QuickBooks Web Connector. I've found various sources that have led me to two possible solutions:

1. [Uninstall the recent KB2918614 security update.](http://uhesse.com/2014/08/31/windows-7-error-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state/)
2. Remove or rename the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto` folder.

I have tried both of these solutions, and I haven't had any luck, but many other people seem to have found at least one of these to work. I will update if I come across anything else that solves my problem.

UPDATE: It turns out that this error, when coming from the QuickBooks Web Connector, may or may not be at all related to the above Windows error during installation of a program. For those who may have encountered this via the WC, check your WC log. In my case, the password for the application somehow got unset, and this caused the WC to crash. Setting the correct password for the application fixed the issue.

Comment: 1. I had tried this before but no luck. 2. Initially I tried renaming the said folder but permission denied / error. So I just deleted it and...it worked! :) Thanks a ton!